# How use data from on script in another

Tags: javascript, node.js, cheerio

I want to automate my work a bit.

I have two files. I want to use an output from the first one (list of links) and use it in the second to go through each of it and pull out some data.

This scrip crates a list of URLs that are listed on our glossary page:

```
const request = require('request');
const cheerio = require('cheerio');
const fs = require('fs');
const writeStream = fs.createWriteStream('links.csv');

request('https://www.myurl.com/glossary', (error, response, html) => {
if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
const $ = cheerio.load(html);

$('div.letter > ul > li').each((i, el) => {
  const link = $(el)
    .find('a')
    .attr('href');

  writeStream.write(`${link} \n`);
});
console.log('Done...');
}
});
```

The second file should look for h1 and .class and put it into .html file form URLs above:

```
const request = require('request');
const cheerio = require('cheerio');
const fs = require('fs');
const writeStream = fs.createWriteStream('data.html');

request('what to put here?', (error, response, html) => {
if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
const $ = cheerio.load(html);

$('div.content').each((i, el) => {
  const term = $(el)
    .find('h1')
    .text();
  const definition = $(el)
    .find('.glossary_short_definition')
    .text();

  writeStream.write(`<h1>${term}</h1> <p>${definition}</p> \n`);
});

console.log('Done...');
 }
});
```

I added import / export to files.

How can I use those URLs in second file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to save the url list to a csv. You can just pass it to the second request wrapped in a function. You can do something like this:

```
const request = require('request');
const cheerio = require('cheerio');
const fs = require('fs');
const writeStream = fs.createWriteStream('data.html');

request('https://www.myurl.com/glossary', (error, response, html) => {
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
  const $ = cheerio.load(html);

  $('div.letter > ul > li').each((i, el) => {
    const link = $(el)
      .find('a')
      .attr('href');

    followUrl(link); // pass the link value to the next request...

  });
  console.log('Done...');
  }
});


function followUrl(link){
  request( link , (error, response, html) => {
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
  const $ = cheerio.load(html);

  $('div.content').each((i, el) => {
    const term = $(el)
      .find('h1')
      .text();
    const definition = $(el)
      .find('.glossary_short_definition')
      .text();

    writeStream.write(`<h1>${term}</h1> <p>${definition}</p> \n`);
  });

  console.log(`Done for url: ${link}`);
   }
  });
}
```

But do you know that you can alternatively do the same with lesser code using [osmosis](https://github.com/rchipka/node-osmosis) instead?

```
const osmosis = require('osmosis');
const fs = require('fs');
const writeStream = fs.createWriteStream('data.html');

osmosis
  .get('https://www.myurl.com/glossary')
  .follow('@href') // browse each href in the url
  .set({
    'term' : 'h1',
    'definition' : '.glossary_short_definition'
  })
  .data((res) => {
    // do something with the data result
    writeStream.write(`<h1>${res.term}</h1> <p>${res.definition}</p> \n`);
  })
  .done((x) => console.log('finished!'))
  .log(console.log)
  .error(console.log)
  .debug(console.log);
```